# How to rotate an object clockwise?

Tags: javascript

How to rotate an object clockwise (without canvas, css3 etc)?

Please see [my example code](http://www.jsfiddle.net/HhxRD/2)

Just help to correct my formula.

Comment: @Algorithm Your demo shows transition which is different from rotation.

Comment: @Šime Vidas I know, but i don't understand how to correct it

Comment: @Algorithm Rotation requires CSS3 - demo: http://vidasp.net/css-transform-demo.html

Comment: @Šime Vidas I know CSS3 wery well, but i'd like to use pure JavaScript

Comment: You can't use "pure JavaScript" — it has no way to render anything. In this context, you can only use it to manipulate an HTML document and its associated technologies. If you want to rotate something that you either need to use CSS 3 (for an HTML element), HTML 5's `<canvas>` (for bitmaps) or SVG (for vectors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it without CSS, but your example code is using CSS for the translation: you're modifying CSS properties by using JavaScript to modify the div's style property.

Try something like:

```
div.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)';
```

To set the angle, assuming you are working with a Webkit browser.

Comment: I can do it without CSS3 transform property, but i can't see how to correct my formula. See it: http://www.jsfiddle.net/HhxRD/25/.                           but I need an arrow.

Comment: @Algorithm Check out my other demo: http://vidasp.net/tinydemos/infinity.html It uses the same technique. It may help you to figure this out.

Comment: @Šime Vidas thanks. But I need an arrow. I'm going to make a clock

Comment: @Algorithm, I figured out the syntax for you.

Comment: @benzado i don't want to use CSS3 or canvas. Just help to correct my formula

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your formula for circular **motion**, but you simply *can't* do rotation without using CSS3 transforms or canvas with Javascript. Cannot be done. Please accept this.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways in which you can rotate your object, both have their own draw backs.

1) You can use php to send back a rotated version of your image. This is fairly easy to do using the GD library.

A positive of this is ofcourse, is that if you use a name like, rotate.php?image=my_image_name&angle=30 then the browser will cache the image for you.

However, there will be a delay with this and so is not a good solution for games.

2) You create the rotations and attached them all to one large sprite sheet. You can then just switch between the sprite image.

However, this does mean you will have a large image file and usually wont have perfect rotation. You can reduce this by rotating in fixed amounts such as 5 degrees, but even with that you will have 72 different versions of your image.

Both of these methods only work with image files them selves and not divs. You can use the images as a background the divs ofcourse.