# drag and rotate an image inside a container

Tags: jquery, rotation, drag

I am able to rotate image clone but it re-position out side the div. is it possible to show that rotate image inside the div. here is the link for jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T6nn5/5/
but the rotate plugin is not included here, so, the image will not rotate.

Comment: did you add `css` of the plugin?

Comment: yes I added all the css of the plugin. if you want you can check my site [here](http://ushatech.com/customer/Palletized_Material_Handling_Conveyors/build.php?num1=50&num2=50)

Comment: i dont see any image rotation goin on by the way where is it? i mean in the website

Comment: i misunderstood your question ... can you add only the rotation script

Comment: <script src="jquery/jQueryRotate.1.7.js"></script>
 var test = 0;                                             $('#working-area .rotatable').live('click', function(event) {
  //alert("hello");
              test = test + 90;
              $(this).rotate({ angle: test , containment: "working-area" }).parent().draggable();
           });

Comment: for both draggable and rotation try http://jsfiddle.net/avPf6/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that the page is set so the user drags and drops a clone of the image on to the grid. When you click on an image, the rotation plugin is called and replaces that image with a `<span><canvas><canvas></span>` (at least in Firefox). That is the reason the drag/drop stopped functioning.

The image is positioned using "absolute" positioning, and the canvas is positioned using "relative" positioning and that's why it ends up below the grid.

I haven't tested this, but I think the solution would be to wrap the image with a `<span>` that has drag/drop functionality applied to it. I don't know if the rotated canvas will once again be wrapped in a relatively positioned `<span>`. So there might still be positioning issues even after this suggested change.

On a side note, when clicking on the canvas, Firebug reports this error:

> $(this).rotate({angle: test,
>   containment: "working-area"}).parent
>   is not a function [Break On This
>   Error] Failed to load source for:
>   http://usha...ng_Conveyors/build.php?num1=50&num2=50
>   build....num2=50 (line 624)

---

**Update:** Here you go, [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/T6nn5/6/) and code:

HTML

```
<li>
    <span class="draggable">
        <img class="rotatable" src="http://www.bootheyankees.com/images/GoogleIcon.png"/>
    </span>
</li>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dhtmlgoodies_xpPane .draggable').draggable({
        scope: "draggable",
        helper: "clone"
    });
    $('#working-area .rotatable').live('click', function(event) {
        test = test + 90;
        $(this).rotate({
            angle: test,
            containment: "working-area"
        });
    });
    $("#working-area").droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        accept: "#dhtmlgoodies_xpPane li .draggable",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone().draggable());

        },
        scope: "draggable"
    }).mousemove(function(e) {
        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        $('#status2').html("X = " + x + ', ' + "Y = " + y);
    });
});
```

Comment: @fudgey thanks for your reply. I didn't understand how to do it. can you please refer some code. here is the link of jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/T6nn5/5/ though here the image will not rotate because of some script will not included here. I am tried s much time but didn't find any solution. I will wait for your reply.

Comment: The error was from chaining `.draggable()` after `.rotate()`... I have a feeling it doesn't return the object and that's why the error was popping up.

Comment: @fudgey after rotation the image is little long than the original image. how to solve this problem.

Comment: A little larger? I can only guess that the rotate plugin may be the cause and that may be an issue you need to bring up with the plugin author.

Comment: @fudgey I am using jQueryRotate.1.7.js plugin for rotation. and it downloaded from someplace, so I don't know who is the author and the solution. am I use some other plugin ? please give some solution.

Comment: Get v2.0 (http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) and if you are still having problems, open an issue... supposedly the size problem was fixed in v1.7 (http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/issues/detail?id=4&can=1), but I guess not if you are having problems.

Answer (score 0):

When you drag an image, your style is `position: absolute; left: 745.5px; top: 788px;` after you click on that image, the style is `position: relative; left: -0.310859px; top: -43.3109px;`. I don't know what your plugin does, but i think you should write your own jquery code. and this certainly is generating an error.

Comment: I also find the same problem but don't know how to solve the problem. I just download the code after simple change it work.I am new to jquery , so please give me some solution.

Comment: @Moumita there's lot of plugins and we don't know what they got in code. I myself don't know how to rotate image (without plugin). I beleive it would be using css (i beleive) ..http://tips4php.net/2010/10/rotate-images-and-text-with-css-3/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348884/how-to-rotate-an-object-clockwise ... however please collect css, and then do it if you can, else you can alert me.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I will try with those css.and I will knock you if any problem will occur.please give some reply

Comment: @Moumita sure i will also check the updated answer by @fudgey it might help